# Why setText is not working?

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to make a app like a NewsFeed with volley an a JSON file, the data displays in cardviews and I want that when the user clicks in the cardviews it opens the whole article and for this I'm using a DialogFragment (i don't find other way) but the problem is that when the dialogfragment opens only shows the default text set in the layout, for now I just want to show the title of each article in the dialogfragment, I know there are a lot of errors in the code and is because is from another app, hope someone can give and advice, thanks.

**MainActivity**

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new MyRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new MyRecyclerAdapter.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("images", datos);
                    bundle.putInt("position", position);

                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Detalles newFragment = Detalles.newInstance();
                    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
                }
```

**Detalles.java**

```
public class Detalles extends DialogFragment{
private String TAG = Detalles.class.getSimpleName();
private ArrayList<NewsFeed> datos;
private TextView tituloon, notoon;

private View viewPager;


 private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private int selectedPosition = 0;
static Detalles newInstance() {
    Detalles f = new Detalles();
    return f;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detalles_completo, container, false);
    tituln = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulon);
    notlnn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noton);
    datos = (ArrayList<NewsFeed>) getArguments().getSerializable("images");
     myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();

    selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");



    return v;

}




private void displayMetaInfo(int position) {

    NewsFeed image = datos.get(position);
    tituln.setText(image.getFeedName());
    notlnn.setText(image.getContent());

}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}



public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.detalles_completo, container, false);


        NewsFeed image = datos.get(position);

        tituln.setText(image.getFeedName());



        container.addView(view);


        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return datos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == ((View) obj);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies for answering rather than commenting - I don't have the required reputation to comment)

It's not clear exactly what you mean by "title" or what you want to display it in, so it's rather difficult to help. I'm going to assume that the title is `datos.get(position).getFeedName()` and that you want to display it in the `TextView` for which a reference is stored in the member variable `tituln`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

If this is indeed what you want to do, it looks like the problem is that none of the code in the dialog fragment actually sets the text. I see that you have a call to `tituln.setText` in the `displayMetaInfo()` method, but this method is never called (at least in the provided code).

If you just want to get the title working, you might like to consider calling `displayMetaInfo()` somewhere. I'd recommend overriding the [`void onViewCreated(View, Bundle)` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)) in `Detalles` and doing it there.